# Отличие Агрегации от N-арной ассоциации в UML?

Tags: java, uml

Чем они отличаются? Описание смотрю тут:  https://habrahabr.ru/post/150041/

Кроме как стрелочкой не получается понять их отличие.

Comment: Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman по ссылке там большая простыня текста, кода и картинок. Тема вопроса, по сути, является самодостаточным вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

Ассоциация - это связь между объектами. Другими словами, ассоциация показывает, что один объект знает о другом(других) объектах и каким-то образом с ними связан.

Агрегация - это объединение объектов. Т.е. один объект включает в себя несколько других объектов.

У Васи есть три друга. Это ассоциация.

У Васи есть две руки - это агрегация.

Так и в том примере с хабра.

Employee знает про несколько объектом Room и связан с ними отношением "работает в". Room не является, да и не может являться, составной частью Employee.

Department содержит в себе несколько объектов типа Employee. Это его суть - содержать в себе сотрудников.

**UPD** Кроме того, если обратите внимание на диаграмму типов отношений, то увидите, что агрегация является подтипом ассоциации.

> Агрегация — это разновидность ассоциации при отношении между целым и
>   его частями.

Ну и на самом деле, выделение N-арной ассоциации в отдельный тип связи - это выдумка автора статьи для упрощения "натягивания UML на код". В UML есть просто ассоциация, которая, в том числе, может быть типа `1..*`